# Помогите установить библиотеку Pygame

Tags: python, pip

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда устанавливал библиотеку,пишет что успешно,
а когда пытаюсь добавить её то выдаёт вот такую ошибку.
Версия питона 3.7.3

Answer (score 1):

1. Приводить здесь скриншоты, которые нужно читать через лупу и из которых **невозможно** ничего скопировать - очень плохая идея.
2. *когда устанавливал библиотеку,пишет что успешно* - это почему Вы так решили? Там же ясно написано *Non-zero exit code*
3. И даже совет даётся: запустить *pip* с правами системного админа.
4. От себя добавлю. Если у Вас установлены обе версии питона - и 2 и 3, то выполнение команды *pip* (скорее всего) запустит установку пакета для второго питона. Если потом запустите третий, то он не увидит установленную библиотеку. Для установки библиотеки для третьего питона, сделайте так: *sudo pip3 install ...*